# Is there ambiguity in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> **Along with** the letter was his promise that he would visit me this coming Christmas.

In this sentence, I am wondering whether the "promise" was written in the "letter" or not?

Answer (score 2):

Logically no.
[*Along with*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/along-with) indicates "his promise" was with the letter (in the envelope or package). If it was in the letter, it would be written something like "(Written) in the letter was his promise...".

> **Along with** the letter I received a gift.

But beyond that it cannot be said how his promise was conveyed.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the sentence given that indicates that the promise was written in the letter. Additional context might help a reader understand that, but there is not enough to go on here, to conclude that. There is not even a suggestion of that, without more context.